# Gradle Could Not Find main class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\data\workspace\dev\tools\java_security for Java 11

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, java-11

I had Gradle which was running through CLI with Java 8. I had to update to Java 11 Azul, but after that it started to give an error

```
C:>gradle
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\data\workspace\dev\tools\java_security
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\data\workspace\dev\tools\java_security
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\data\workspace\dev\tools\java_security
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\data\workspace\dev\tools\java_security
```

I have added certificates(cacerts) to `<azul-jdk11-location>/lib/security` directory from `<oracle-jdk8-location>/jre/lib/security`

Here are my versions:

```
C:>%JAVA_HOME%
'C:\Java\JDK11\Azul' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:>%GRADLE_HOME%
'C:\Gradle\gradle-5.4\bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Weirdly my java version is still Java 8 after changing `JAVA_HOME`

```
C:>java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

I am able to run Gradle project from IDE giving the Gradle and JDK11 path. I want to run Gradle through CLI. Is there a misconfiguration on my machine?

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: C:\data\workspace\dev\tools\java_security` - Is your classpath set correctly?

Comment: Which classpath? How can i check classpath for security?

Comment: _Weirdly my java version is still Java 8 after changing JAVA_HOME_ Windows searches the PATH environment variable to locate file `java.exe`. The output of the [Windows] command `where java` will show you where Windows finds file `java.exe`.

Comment: Java 11 is modular while Java 8 is not. You may need to set `module-path` rather than (or in addition to) CLASSPATH.

Comment: Java doesn’t care about `%JAVA_HOME%`. When you enter `java` as a command, the command line interpreter will search for the `java.exe` in its command search path. There are two possibilities: it finds a `java.exe` with in a JRE or JDK. That executable will use the installation it belongs to. Or it finds a `java.exe` in its system directory that will use the registry to discover installed java versions and select one (newer JDKs don’t use this anymore). Besides that, the error message says that someone tried to load `C:\data\workspace\dev\tools\java_security` as a class. That can’t work.

Comment: I do not see Gradle calling java_security? Is there a configuration I am missing here?